# Get Focus Control from all window forms using Delphi

Tags: delphi, object, text, focus, controls

I am interested to get title/caption/text from all controls focused by the mouse in Delphi.

So moving the mouse after all controls from any windows i am interesting to retrieve the current object caption reached using the mouse.

Example: Narrator from Windows

Answer (score 1):

You'll need [GetCursorPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the coordinates of the cursor on the screen and then use [WindowFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the windowhandle of the window/control at that location. After you've got the window handle, you can use it to retrieve or change the properties of the window/control with the Win32 api.

I found this example that shows you how to get the classname of a window/control using this method: http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2000/a/bltip1200_2.htm

Comment: There is any method to cast these objects?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... What objects are you referring to?