# Any method to cast a Handle?

Tags: windows, delphi, casting, handle

Good day,

I have different handles from different non VLC Objects like (SysListView32, ToolbarWin32) and I am wondering if there is any method to cast these handles (HWND).

For example, I got the start button(which is in the left bottom of desktop) handle. Then I found the class name "Button".

I would like to cast him and retrieve from him the caption property "start". For example:

```
type 
  TButtonStartMenuFictiveClass = class(TButton)
  public
    Text: string;
  end;

if classname = 'button' then
begin
  ShowMessage((objecthandle as TButtonStartMenuFictiveClass).Text);
end;
```

I am looking to hook all of the objects and to display the text of them. Like the narrator from Windows.

Comment: I don't really understand who Microsoft wrote the Narrator

Comment: You can't cast an HWND into a Delphi class, for the same reason you can't typecast a bicycle into a Ferrari just because they both have tires. Typecasting can't transform something into something it's absolutely not; a typecast can't perform magic. You can't typecast the Handle of a Delphi `TEdit` (which is an `HWND`) into a `TTreeView` (which also has an `HWND` Handle) and access the nodes, either, because a `TEdit` isn't a `TTreeView`.

Comment: Search for Microsoft Active Accessibility (MSAA) and/or UIAutomation. Be prepared to find that these frameworks are easier to use from other languages

Comment: @Ken, but it would be nice to typecast a bicycle into a Ferrari :-)

Comment: @TLama, especially if you could do it more than once. You could get pretty rich - I guess that would be a true case of being able to buy low and sell high. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I explained in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862817/get-focus-control-from-all-window-forms-using-delphi), you need to use the Windows API to gain access to the properties of a foreign window-control. You can't simply cast a window-handle to an object. They're not pointers to Delphi objects.

The example I linked you too not only shows the classname of the control you're hovering over, but also the caption (text) of the control. This function will also do the trick:

```
function GetWndText(const Handle: Hwnd): string;
var
  Len: Integer;
begin
  Len := GetWindowTextLength(Handle) + 1;
  SetLength(Result, Len);
  GetWindowText(Handle, PChar(Result), Len);
end;
```

Comment: You can't use `GetWindowTextLength()` and `GetWindowText()` if the `HWND` belongs to another process than the caller. The documentation says as much. You have to directly send `WM_GETTEXTLEN` and `WM_GETTEXT` messages to the `HWND` instead.

Comment: I'm aware that the documentation says this, but I've never actually experienced this limitation myself. If you'll try the function, you see it works fine in other processes.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases, you can instantiate a VCL object and assign the external `HWND` to its `WindowHandle` property, eg:

```
var
  S: String;

with TButton.Create(nil) do
try
  WindowHandle := TheButtonWnd;
  try
    S := Caption;
  finally
    WindowHandle := 0; // important
  end;
finally
  Free;
end;
```

Comment: That's not typecasting an HWND to a Delphi object, though, which is what the question asked.

Comment: The purpose of typecasting is to convert/access a value of one type as if it were another type. Obviously an `HWND` cannot be typecasted to a VCL object, but it can be accessed as one. The question did ask how to access a property of the `HWND` as if it were from a VCL object, so I provided a way to do that. Different technique, same result.